# Android - Cut drawable image programmatically

Tags: android, drawable

How can I cut some pixels from a drawable image? Like, I have a horizontal bar, and I want to show just 50% of that bar. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

This is how you crop an image from a given image:

```
// Given image is named "girl" in drawable folder
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.girl).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
// Create a bit map with width and heigh = 100 pixel
Bitmap image2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
            // Set color of each pixel of created image to color of given image                     
            mage2.setPixel(i, j, image.getPixel(i, j));
    }
}
```

For your problem, just create a image with width and height equals half of width and height of your given image, then set whatever pixel in wherever you want!

Comment: But I have to crop directly on a Drawable object. Maybe using the Level of Drawable workes? But I don't know how to use the level on a Drawable object.